# Один из параметров JSON в качестве значения переменной

Tags: python, json

долго думал но так и не получилось сделать чтобы работало но я знаю что подобное можно.

У меня следующий код

```
jsoncod = "https://SITE/category/initCall?service_id=ID&key=KEY&phone=" + phone + "&client=test"
    response = requests.get(jsoncod)
    print(response.json())
    print(response[0]["ucaller_id"])
```

Мы получаем параметр из get запроса и записываем его в jsoncod.
Как мне из jsoncod вывести определённое значение?

Так выглядит json:

```
{
    "status": true, 
    "ucaller_id": 103000, 
    "code": 7777, 
    "client": "nickname", 
}
```

В результате я должен получить переменную в которой будет значение ucaller_id тоесть 103000

(статьи с этого же сайта не помогли)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл выход сам.

```
    jsoncod = "https://SITE/category/initCall?service_id=ID&key=KEY&phone=" + phone + "&client=test"  
    response = requests.get(jsoncod)
    response1 = response.json()
    print(response1)
    print(response1['ucaller_id'])
    print('Звонок отправлен!')
```

Пришлось попотеть чтобы это сделать на питоне...

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import json
phone = '+7922250000'

url = f"https://SITE/category/initCall?service_id=ID&key=KEY&phone={phone}&client=test"
response = requests.get(
    url
)

try:
    data: dict = response.json()
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    print('check the number')
else:
    print(data.get('ucaller_id'))
```

Если не поможет, шлите живой url сайта
Но параметры `service_id=ID&key=KEY` меня откровенно смущают.   Надеюсь у Вас в рабочей версии поставлены реальные ID и KEY